Deriving the plane wave scattering from a conducting half plate
Consider the two-dimensional problem of a plane wave of angular frequency $\omega$ propagating in the direction $\hat{\textbf{k}}=cos(\phi^{i})\hat{\textbf{x}}+sin(\phi^{i})\hat{\textbf{y}}$ impinging on a half infinite, perfectly conducting plate located at $y=0$, $x>0$. The $z$ component of the electric field, $E_{z}$, satisfies the Helmholtz equation:
$$
(\nabla^{2}+k_{0}^{2})E_{z}=0
$$
where $k_{0}=\omega/c$ is the wavenumber, along with the boundary condition $E_{z}=0$ on the plate. I would like to derive the solution:
$$
E_{z}=2E_{0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-in\pi/4}J_{n/2}(k_{0}\rho)sin\left(\frac{n\phi}{2}\right)sin\left(\frac{n(\pi+\phi^{i})}{2}\right)
$$
where $E_{0}$ is the incident field amplitude, $J_{n}$ is the order $n$ Bessel function of the first kind and $\rho$ and $\phi$ are the usual plane polar coordinates. I have the general solution satisfying the boundary condition:
$$
E_{z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e_{n}J_{n/2}(k_{0}\rho)sin\left(\frac{n\phi}{2}\right)
$$
(ensuring non-singularity at the edge of the plate, $\rho=0$). However, I'm having a few difficulties matching to the incident field. I know I can write the incident field as a Bessel function expansion as follows:
$$
E_{0}e^{ik_{0}\rho cos(\phi-\phi^{i})}=E_{0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}i^{n}J_{n}(k_{0}\rho)e^{in(\phi-\phi^{i})}
$$
However, I'm stuck as to how to use this to show that the unknown coefficients should be given by:
$$
e_{n}=2E_{0}e^{-in\pi/4}sin\left(\frac{n(\pi+\phi^{i})}{2}\right)
$$
Thanks in advance for any help.
